# Simplest way of using dpkg-buildpackage with an existing upstream source tarball

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

Been reading hundreds of tutorials and still cannot my head around to this one:

- I have an upstream package provided by upstream, called foo-1.2.3.tar.bz2.
- I put the file in /tmp/debplayground/.
- The way to install that package manually would be cd /tmp/debplayground/ && tar -xvf foo-1.2.3.tar.bz2 && cd foo-1.2.3 && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install
- I want my package to be named "special-foo".
- I want just to generate a binary package (.deb file), not interested in a source package.

Given the above premises, here are my questions:

1. To be able to create basic debian pkg files via 'dh_make -i --createorig' I need to create a folder called "special-foo-1.2.3" and call dh inside there, right? But then do I need to rename foo-1.2.3.tar.bz2 to special-foo-1.2.3.tar.bz2?
2. Do I need to uncompress the .tar.bz2 or dpkg-buildpackage does it for me?
3. Where do I need to place the upstream tarball in relation to the debian/ folder created by dh_make so dpkg-buildpackage calls ./configure and make correctly?

Answer (score 1):

1. dh_make is a little bit silly in this regard. I wouldn't too much time figuring out how to make it happy; all you really need to care about is the packaging template that it sets up. To answer what I think your question is here, if you're not creating a "native" package, dpkg-buildpackage will expect to find a file called `../special-foo_1.2.3.orig.tar.{gz,bz2,lzma}` when building in order to correctly generate the `.diff.gz` part of the source package, which is supposed to identify any changes to the upstream source in the Debian package. dh_make generally makes a symlink for you when you tell it what the upstream tarball is.
2. You do need to uncompress the original .tar.bz2 at least once, in order to put your packaging information in place (see #3). But you don't need to decompress it after that; dpkg-source (called by dpkg-buildpackage when appropriate) will do it by itself in a tmp dir when it needs to generate new diffs.
3. Your `debian/` folder should be at the top level of the package source tree. In your case, it would be `/tmp/debplayground/foo-1.2.3/debian`.